# Python: how to create a custom CLI command with space?

Tags: python

I'm learning python, a total noob... In a tutorial I have this command:

```sh
@cli.command('seed_db')
def seed_db():
    db.session.add(User(username='username_1', email="info@gmail.com"))
    db.session.add(User(username='username_2', email="info@example.com"))
    db.session.commit()
```

So I can launch it with `python manage.py seed_db`

Now, I'm integrating Flask Migrate and I want create another custom command

```
@cli.command('migrate_db')
def migrate_db():
    db migrate

@cli.command('upgrade_db')
def upgrade_db():
    db upgrade
```

Of course, I got "syntax error" for that space (the commands itselfs work, I'm using it via Flask Shell)

How can I use it? I did try putting them between quotation marks without success (no output in console).

### Solved:

```
@cli.command('db')
def migrate():
    migrate

def upgrade():
    upgrade
```

Comment: Try changing `db migrate`to `db.migrate()`

Comment: With that, I got answer from SQLAlchemy: "AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'migrate'"

Comment: What are you doing after all with these methods?

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time. I got it finally :)